# Distance from a weak* closed subspace is achieved by an element?

Tags: functional-analysis, banach-spaces

Let $X$ denotes a separable Banach space and $X^{*}$ its dual space. Let $M\subseteq X^{*}$ be a weak* closed subspace of $X^{*}.$ Let $\varphi\in X^{*}\setminus M$ be given. I have the following question:

is it true that there exists a $\psi\in M$ such that $$\inf\{||\varphi-m||:m\in M\}=||\varphi-\psi||,$$

where $||.||$ denotes the operator norm of linear functionals on $X^{*}?$

Comment: The balls $K_r(\varphi) := \{ \psi \in X^{\ast} : \lVert \varphi - \psi\rVert \leqslant r\}$ are weak$^{\ast}$-compact. So $K_r(\varphi) \cap M$ is …? (And separability of $X$ is irrelevant.)

Comment: yes it will also be compact.

Comment: So if we let $A_r = K_r(\varphi) \cap M$, and consider $$A := \bigcap_{r > \operatorname{dist}(\varphi,M)} A_r,$$ what can we deduce?

Comment: This will also be weak* compact but will it be nonempty?

Comment: Yes, it will. There is a very important thing about intersections of compact sets. If we have a family $\{C_{\alpha} : \alpha \in A\}$ of compact sets, and [some condition], then $\bigcap\limits_{\alpha\in A} C_{\alpha} \neq \varnothing$. What is the condition?

Comment: finite intersection property?

Comment: Yes, the finite intersection property. For our $A_r$, that's clear since the $A_r$ are nested.

Comment: I think I got you. I mean the intersection will be nonempty and so if we choose an element $\varphi_0\in M$ in the intersection then we have $||\varphi-\varphi_{0}||\leq \text{dist}(\varphi,M).$

Comment: Right. Because $\bigcap\limits_{r > \rho} K_r(\varphi) = K_{\rho}(\varphi)$.

Comment: One more question is this $\varphi_0$ is unique? I mean it seems it depends on the norm of $X?$ And also it will be good if you can write the solution here, or if you don't want I can write the same.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The separability of $X$ is irrelevant here. From the Banach-Alaoglu theorem, we know that for all $\varphi \in X^{\ast}$ and $r \geqslant 0$ the norm-closed ball $K_r(\varphi) := \{ \psi \in X^{\ast} : \lVert \varphi - \psi\rVert \leqslant r\}$ is weak$^{\ast}$-compact.

Then if $S$ is any weak$^{\ast}$-closed nonempty subset of $X^{\ast}$, the family $\{S\cap K_r(\varphi) : r > \operatorname{dist}(\varphi,S)\}$ is a family of nonempty weak$^{\ast}$-compact sets. Since the family is nested, it has the finite intersection property, and therefore

$$\bigcap_{r > \operatorname{dist}(\varphi,S)} S\cap K_r(\varphi) = S \cap K_{\operatorname{dist}(\varphi,S)}(\varphi) \neq \varnothing.$$

But $S \cap K_{\operatorname{dist}(\varphi,S)}(\varphi)$ is just the set of elements of $S$ that achieve the distance,

$$S \cap K_{\operatorname{dist}(\varphi,S)}(\varphi) = \{\psi \in S : \lVert \varphi - \psi\rVert = \operatorname{dist}(\varphi,S)\}.$$

So whatever the nonempty weak$^{\ast}$-closed subset, the distance is always achieved.

The set $S \cap K_{\operatorname{dist}(\varphi,S)}(\varphi)$ may or may not be a singleton. It is always a singleton if $\varphi\in S$ (trivially). It is also a singleton if the set $S$ is convex [e.g. a linear subspace] and the operator norm on $X^{\ast}$ is strictly convex (that is, the unit sphere contains no line segment), for if we have two distinct points $\psi_1,\psi_2\in S$ with $\lVert \varphi - \psi_1\rVert = \lVert \varphi - \psi_2\rVert$, and $S$ is convex, then $\psi_3 = \frac{1}{2}(\psi_1 + \psi_2) \in S$, and if the norm is strictly convex, then $\lVert \varphi - \psi_3\rVert < \lVert \varphi - \psi_1\rVert$, so $\lVert \varphi - \psi_1\rVert > \operatorname{dist}(\varphi,S)$ then.

If the operator norm is not strictly convex, the distance can be achieved in multiple points. E.g. if we take $X = \mathbb{R}^2$ endowed with the $\ell^1$-norm, then $X^{\ast}$ is (isometrically isomorphic to) $\mathbb{R}^2$ endowed with the maximum-norm. Then we can take $M = \{(x,0) : x \in \mathbb{R}\}$ and $\varphi = (0,1)$, and we see that the distance is achieved for all $(x,0)$ with $\lvert x\rvert \leqslant 1$. If on the other hand we take a subspace $M = \mathbb{R}\cdot (a,b)$ with $ab\neq 0$, then the point achieving the distance is unique.

Comment: Thanks for a really nice presentation.

Answer (score 0):

Yes this is true and it can be proven along the following lines:

- find a sequence $\{\psi_n\} \subset M$, such that $\|\psi_n - \varphi\| \to \inf\{\|\varphi - m\| : m \in M\}$
- extract a weak-$*$ convergent subsequence with limit $\psi$
- conclude that $\psi$ has the desired properties

Comment: yes, I did that I mean using the Banach Alaoglou Theorem we find a sequence $\{\psi_n\}$ in $M$ such that $\psi_n$ converges to $\psi\in M$ in weak* topology and also we have $\text{dist}(\varphi, M)\leq ||\varphi-\psi_n||\leq\text{dist}(\varphi, M)+\frac{1}{n}\forall n\in\mathbb{N}.$ After that I'm not able to see how to proceed.

Comment: You need to bound $\|\varphi - \psi\|$ by means of $\lim_{n\to\infty}\|\varphi - \psi_n\|$.