# A question in Functional Analysis

Tags: functional-analysis, banach-spaces, topological-vector-spaces, dual-spaces

This is an exercise in Rudin's Functional Analysis.

Let $X$ be a Banach space and let $Y$ be a closed subspace of $X$. Let $x_0^*\in X^*$, $\mu=\sup\{|x_0^*(x)|:x\in Y, \|x\|\leq 1\}$ and let $\delta=\inf\{\|x^*-x^*_0\|:x^*\in Y^{\perp}\}$. I want to show that $\mu=\delta$.  Also I need to show that there exists $x^*\in Y^{\perp}$ such that $\delta=\|x^*-x_0^*\|$.

I proceed in this way:

Let $x\in Y$ and $\|x\|\leq 1$. Then  for all $x^*\in Y^{\perp}$, $|x_0^*(x)|=|x^*(x)-x^*_0(x)|\leq \|x^*-x_0^*\|\|x\|\leq \|x^*-x_0^*\|$. Thus $\mu\leq \delta$. But how to show that $\delta\leq \mu$? Any suggestion is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $y^{\ast} := x_0^{\ast}\lvert_Y$, then $y^{\ast}\in Y^{\ast}$ and
$$
\mu = \|y^{\ast}\|
$$
By Hahn-Banach, $\exists z^{\ast} \in X^{\ast}$ such that $z^{\ast}\lvert_Y = y^{\ast}$ and $\|z^{\ast}\| = \|y^{\ast}\| = \mu$. But $x^{\ast} := x_0^{\ast}-z^{\ast} \in Y^{\perp}$, so
$$
\delta \leq \|x^{\ast} - x_0^{\ast}\| = \|z^{\ast}\| = \mu
$$

Comment: Since $Y^{\perp}$ is weak*-closed in $X^*$, therefore by https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1528227/distance-from-a-weak-closed-subspace-is-achieved-by-an-element?noredirect=1&lq=1  there exists $x^*\in Y^{\perp}$ such that $\|x^*-x_0^*\|=\delta$. But I could not understand where we have used the fact that $Y$ is closed. @ Prahlad Vaidyanathan.